# The property '#/' of type Hash did not match one or more of the required schemas

Tags: php, json

I'm trying to add a user to a list through an API. However, I'm getting this error returned:

```
{"errors":[{"code":"parsing_error","message":"JSON parsing error: The property '#/' of type Hash did not match one or more of the required schemas"}]}
```

This is what I'm sending: `{"subscribers":{"email":"me@gmail.com"}}`

Here is the PHP code:

```
$subscriberInfo = [
    'subscribers' => array (
        'email' => $email
    )
];

$encoded = json_encode($subscriberInfo);
```

Is there something wrong with the structure of the JSON?

Comment: What does the API documentation say about it?

Comment: It seems like "an API" expects not just a valid json, but a json with a specific set of fields.

Comment: API docs: https://www.getdrip.com/docs/rest-api?#subscribers

Comment: Under "Create or update a subscriber"

Comment: Email or ID are the only required fields

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's not the format described in the documentation. `subscribers` should be an array, not an object:

```
$subscriberInfo = [
    'subscribers' => [
        ['email' => $email]
    ]
];

$encoded = json_encode($subscriberInfo);
```

Comment: I agree, I also noticed that for the example request the doc said `Content-Type: application/vnd.api+json` so I wonder if that content type should be manually set, vs the json default of `application/json`

Comment: @chiliNUT - Yeah, I set it later in the code. But thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 0):

Another possible issue that I encountered when receiving the same error code is that it didn't like a `null` value.

```php
$firstName = 'Paul';
$lastName = null;

$subscriberInfo = [
    'subscribers' => [
        [
            'email' => $email,
            'first_name' => $firstName,
            'last_name' => $lastName,
        ],
    ]
];
```

With the [null coalescing operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op), it can fall back to an empty string.

```php
$firstName = 'Paul';
$lastName = null;

$subscriberInfo = [
    'subscribers' => [
        [
            'email' => $email,
            'first_name' => $firstName,
            'last_name' => $lastName ?? '',
        ],
    ]
];
```

The above snippet resolved my error code when attempting a batch subscriber 'create or update'.